# Choosing a specific day using "moment" javascript

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

Is there a way to choose a specific day using "moment" in javascript?
For example, say the date is June 20, 2020. I want to go back one month and go to the specific date the 15th (May 15th, 2020)

So far I have:

```js
const date = moment();
date.subtract(1, 'month');
```

Which would give me the May part, but I'm unsure about the 15th. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
const date = moment();
date.subtract(1, 'month');
date.date(15);
```

This should do it.
Refer [here](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/date/)

Comment: Hello, this doesnt seem to work. On jsfiddle it seems to be undefined. I tried doing date.set(15, 'date'); instead, but it still shows me today's date (19th), not the 15th. Thoughts?

Edit: I did:
const date = moment();
const temp = moment().subtract(1, 'month').set('date', 15);

Answer (score 0):

You have an answer with moment.js, bit it's not that difficult with POJS either:

```js
// Create a Date
let d = new Date();
// Set to 15th of previous month
d.setMonth(d.getMonth() - 1, 15);

console.log(d.toString());
```